# Playing .m4v videos one after another. How to program a video playlist with SMIL for QuickTime

Tags: video, quicktime, playlist, smil

I have .m4v video scene files organized in an identical folder structures on my own server. Right now users can watch those videos one by one and have to click to go to the next or previous one. Scenes are 1-4 minutes long. I want to give the option to play all scenes that belong to an episode one after another.

I am aware that this could be done with SMIL. Is this the best way to do it? I am capable to do basic scripting in HTML and other languages.

Users should be able to click on a button called "Play complete video". A new window should open and the first movie of this episode should start. There should be next and previous buttons to jump to the next scene.

Since the folder structure is identical and all video files are named 01.m4v / 02.m4v a.s.o. the solution should be as generic as possible.

Best would be that I just define the name of the episode (which is part of the first folder name) and the script should gather and calculate the rest automatically.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SMIL (Synchronized Multimedia Integration Language) is no silver bullet.  It's nothing more than an (obscure) XML-based format for describing things such as playlist sequences.  Without some sort of library that parses the SMIL and tells your video player what to do with it, it doesn't help you.   So, if you really want to use SMIL, you'll need to either write your own parser or find a library that allows it.  I don't believe any such library exists right now independent of a larger, more robust player solution.

Based on the description of your problem, though, I think you either need:

1. Your own lightweight script-based solution that takes advantage of the methods and events exposed by the <video> tag to navigate the user between your videos.
   Methods: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video#IDL_Attributes_and_Methods

   Events: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video#Media_Events
   You could certainly use SMIL as the format for describing the sequences.
2. A robust video player that can support scripted navigation between clips.   The JW player (http://www.jwplayer.com/) is a popular choice, although I only see SMIL support explicitly documented in relation to their OpenVideoAds support, so again, you'd probably need to implement your own functionality that scripts the player based on the parsed SMIL.